# GWT how to add css style on Image Resource

Tags: css, image, gwt, styles, clientresource

I am using GWT. I have an Image Resource object. for example,

```
 ImageResource image = ClientResources.of().images().icon();
```

How can I add some css styles on this image. Since this is ImageResource, not the Image object, I cannot use image.addStyleName(). I am not using ui-binder. So how could I achieve this?

Because I am newb in GWT, if you answer could provide some codes, that would be more clear and really appreciated.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you displaying the image? You can't perform CSS operations on an `ImageResource` directly, but neither can you display it directly. You have to stick it in an `Image`, `ImageResourceCell`, or some other object, all of which *are* able to be styled. So you'd want to style the renderer, not the `ImageResource` itself.

For example:

```
ImageResource imageResource = ClientResources.of().images().icon();
Image image = new Image(imageResource);
image.addStyleName("someCoolStyle");
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with an `ImageResourceCell` any chance you can help me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139282/how-to-apply-a-css-style-to-the-imageresourcecell-part-of-a-compositecell-in-gwt